# MyFaces is acusing duplicate id that isn't duplicated

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

I have an strange problem happening in my web application after I changed Mojarra to MyFaces...
I have a xhtml file that is loaded from outside, in other words, this xhtml is reused a lot:

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/popup.xhtml">
<ui:param name="titulo" value="#{modeloPopup.rotulo}"/>
<ui:param name="popup" value="#{modeloPopup}"/>
<ui:param name="controladorPopup" value="#{controladorPopup}"/>
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:panelGroup id="painelPopup" layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form clearfix" style="width: 400px">
        <p:focus for="inputValor"/>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <p:fieldset styleClass="fieldset-novo-registro" legend="#{msgGerais['gerais.novo_registro']}">
                <h:outputLabel for="inputValor" value="#{modeloPopup.tituloNome}" styleClass="hrgi-label-form"/>
                <p:inputText id="inputValor" value="#{modeloPopup.elemento.valor}" maxlength="50" style="width: 210px"/>
            </p:fieldset>
            <p:commandButton value="#{msgGerais['gerais.adicionar']}" action="#{controladorPopup.adicionarValor}"
                             update="painelPopup alerta" style="margin-top: 10px;"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="painelLista" binding="#{bindingPainel}" layout="block" styleClass="clearfix">
            <p:dataTable id="lista" var="bean" value="#{modeloPopup.lista}" scrollable="#{modeloPopup.lista.size()>5}"
                         height="145" rowEditListener="#{controladorPopup.editarValor}" onRowEditUpdate="alerta">
                <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{bean.valor}" style="width:80%">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bean.valor}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{bean.valor}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{msgGerais['gerais.acoes']}" style="width:20%">
                    <p:rowEditor/>
                    <p:commandLink action="#{controladorPopup.removerValor(bean)}"
                                   style="text-align: center;margin: auto;"
                                   update="#{bindingPainel.clientId} alerta confirmacao" immediate="true">
                        <h:graphicImage library="img" name="remover.png"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

this xhtml is used this way:

```
<h:form id="cadastroRamoAtividade">
<ui:include src="resources/components/popups/modulo_cadastro/popupCadastroString.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="modeloPopup" value="#{modeloPopupCadastroRamoAtividade}"/>
    <ui:param name="controladorPopup" value="#{controladorPopupCadastroRamoAtividade}"/>
    <ui:param name="idPopup" value="popupNovoCadastroRamoAtividade"/>
    <ui:param name="bindingPainel" value="#{painelListaRamoAtividade}"/>
</ui:include>
</h:form>
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
[#|2012-04-26T10:25:14.527-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.IllegalStateException: component with duplicate id "cadastroRamoAtividade:popupNovoCadastroRamoAtividade:lista" found
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:54)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIdsStatefulComponents(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:35)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.saveView(DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.java:489)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:189)
at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:253)
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartialRendering(PartialViewContextImpl.java:550)
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:388)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:402)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:755)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1900)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at fr.xebia.servlet.filter.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(De|#]
[#|2012-04-26T10:25:14.529-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|faultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

|#]

I've looked at html source at chrome and didn't found any repeated id...
Someone knows how can I solve it??

Comment: I *guess* that `<h:panelGroup binding="#{bindingPainel}">` is the root cause of this problem. Try removing that `binding` attribute and retry.

Comment: Solved, but now I'm using complete id in all my f:ajax tags, cause of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666631/jsf-fajax-cannot-locate-component-on-context). Please @BalusC, create a answer for me mark as solved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *guess* that `<h:panelGroup binding="#{bindingPainel}">` is the root cause of this problem. If you have multiple components with the same `binding` in the same view, then you will get this exception. The `binding` attribute must point to an unique and request based variable.

Comment: sorry i have to ask.. *multiple components with the same binding*
are you refering to elements inside the panelGroup? (e.g. added via bindingPanel.getChildren.add(something))